# How do I write Junit setup functionality that works at either a suite or class level?

Tags: java, junit, categories

I have `@BeforeClass` setup that I run run for a test suite, like so:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(IntegrationTest.class)
.
.
.
public class IntegrationTestSuite {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialise() throws Exception {
        // Integration test-specific config.
    }
}
```

This works well when I have all my tests running through the suite. However, when I run individual tests, obviously this stuff won't be executed. Is there a more elegant way that would allow me to reuse the test category setup at a test case level?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310319/junit-4-test-suite-and-individual-test-classes?rq=1). That question is two years old so I figured it would be worth seeing if JUnit has moved ahead some. Also, whether what I want to do could be achieved with rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a custom rule (possibly utilizing [ExternalResourse](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html)) that will execute the initialization only once. Using a mechanism where one test does initialization for other tests is an anti-pattern. It is too brittle because it depends on the order in which the tests are run and also fails when only a single test is run. I think the `@Rule` mechanism is a much better solution.

Comment: That looks really promising. While it's possibly outside the scope of what I'm asking, are you then able to apply a rule programatically based on category? So for instance, apply an an integration type `ExternalResource` that applies some config, or start a SoapUI mock for unit testing. The other possibility is that the use of `Category` is still too experimental to do exactly what I'm after at the moment.

Comment: To clarify further, I have a bunch of tests in a single class, denoted by `IntegrationTest.class` or `UnitTest.class`, for example. My suites then use those categories accordingly. Looking at some `ExternalResource` examples, it looks as though the `@Rule` is applied at the class level, irrespective of the `@Category`...

Comment: I am not familiar with the use of `Category` in conjuction with `Rule`

Comment: I was thinking you would have one implementation of the `Rule` for tests in one `Category` and a different implementation of the `Rule` for test in another `Category`

Comment: Maybe my understanding of this is flawed because I can't think how I would write a rule that would only apply to certain tests in a class. Do you know of an example that might clarify this?

Comment: I was thinking that all tests in a class were in same category.

Comment: Ah ok. It may not be the best way to go about things, but you answer definitely helped me to get to close enough to what I was after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use a global flag as static context or in a properties file as :

```
public static boolean runTestCaseStandAlone = false;
```

or

```
boolean runTestCaseStandAlone = properties.get("run.test.case.alone");
```

Updated test suite method as:

```
public class IntegrationTestSuite {
 @BeforeClass
 public static void initialise() throws Exception {
   if(!GLOBALCONTEXT.runTestCaseStandAlone){
       // Integration test-specific config.
   }
  }
 }
```

Create a Base class for your test case e.g.

```
public class BaseTest ....
 @BeforeClass
 public static void initialise() throws Exception {
   if(GLOBALCONTEXT.runTestCaseStandAlone){
       // Integration test-specific config.
   }
  }
```

Make sure all your individual test cases extend the above base class.